# Calibrate exposure in RawTherapee using a grey scale

Tags: post-processing, exposure, dynamic-range, gray-card, rawtherapee

I just got a grey card which comes with a 11 levels grey scale :

```
L 18.9 | Ev −2 | Ev −1.5 | Ev −1 | Ev −0.5 | L 50 Ev 0 | Ev +0.5 | Ev +1 | Ev +1.5 | Ev +2 | L 98.2
```

How do I take advantage of this chart to calibrate exposure in post using RawTherapee ?  Should I set `L*` to 18.9 % on the black end and 92.2 % on the white end ?  And are "black" and "exposure compensation" the right settings to adjust ?

[This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/96890/43103) to [Unclear whether grey card can be used for exposure in post production?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96870) provides hints, but RawTherapee's highlights & shadows sliders don't seem to provide the expected effect, and most online resources focus on white balance only.

Comment: A gray card is not for white balance calibration. It is for exposure. The ranges are probably for dynamic range. White balance is only if the grays are really neutral gray.

Comment: @Rafael And it’s off-topic anyway, question edited.

Answer (score 1):

After [some further reading](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Exposure) I feel a reasonable workflow would be

1. set white balance using the pipette on the 18 % grey area ;
2. add a color picker (I wonder if there is a better tool ?) in the black (L 18.9) area and another in the white (L 98.2) area ;
3. adjust the white point with the *Exposure compensation* slider ;
4. adjust the black point with the *Black* slider ;
5. go back to step 3 if necessary until the color pickers values are as close as 18.9 % and 98.2 %.

It seems to give reasonable results, though I wonder if this is the best workflow.